# Unity2D: troubles with spawning script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn

So basically I have a spawning script (2D game) that spawns in a enemy after spawn delay. I've also adding an array of enemy prefabs so that the SpawnerScript will spawn in a random enemy. However I'm  having some problems with spawning in the prefabs in a random position within a transform (a.k.a: a 3D cube). You see My spawner isn't spawning in anything when I play the game, I made sure that I have included the size of how many enemies I want to spawn in. and made sure I have attach my prefabs. I also made sure that my unity project file hasn't got a bug. Maybe my code is wrong, i'm not sure.

My SpawnerScript:

```
public float RateOfSpawn = 1;
public float spawnTime = 2;

public GameObject[] enemy;

void Start(){
    InvokeRepeating ("addEnemy", spawnTime, spawnTime);
}

void Spawn () {           
    // Random position within this transform- 3Dcube

    var x1 = transform.position.x - GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x / 2;
    var x2 = transform.position.x + GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x / 2;

    var spawnPoint = new Vector2 (Random.Range (x1, x2), transform.position.y);
    int enemyIndex = enemy.Length;
    Instantiate (enemy[enemyIndex],spawnPoint,Quaternion.identity); 
 }
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the proper function to make it work.

```
void Start()
{    
    InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
}
```

You have to call `"Spawn"` instead of `"addEnemy"`.

Also change `Instanatiate` for proper instantiation.

```
Instantiate (enemy[Random.Range (0, enemyIndex)], spawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
```

`enemy[Random.Range (0, enemyIndex)]` helps you choose random enemy from array of enemies' index `0` to `enemyIndex-1`.

The cause of exception is putting the length of array as index. Max Index limit is always length-1.

Comment: Thank you but I got this error: IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
SpawnScript.Spawn ()

Comment: The IndexOutOfRangeException is caused because you´r trying  to accsess an array element that´s not existing. You have to substract 1 to the enemyIndex variable: int enemyIndex = enemy.Length -1;

Comment: Yep, edited as needed. Max limit is exclusive in case of integer range. So no need of subtraction.  OP putting direct length caused the exception. Even if OP subtracted 1 from length, there would be just one game object instantiated all the time.